# OpenLayers 4 Map Projection Issue

Tags: openlayers, proj

I've been trying to do project my map in OpenLayers 4 into Massachusetts Mainland (EPSG:26986). I was following this example: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/scaleline-indiana-east.html but after plugging in the MA Mainland values I just get a blank screen. Here is my code:

```
<script>
proj4.defs('EPSG=26986', 'PROJCS["NAD83 / Massachusetts Mainland",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",' +
SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],' +
'UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],' +
'PARAMETER["false_easting",200000],' +
'PARAMETER["false_northing",750000],' +
'PARAMETER[""central_meridian",-71.5],' +
'PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",41],' +
'UNIT["metre"]]');

var map = new ol.Map({
layers: [
new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.OSM()
})
],
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
projection: 'EPSG=26986',
center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-71, 42], 'EPSG=26986'),
zoom: 7,
extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([-172.54, 23.81, -47.74, 86.46],
'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG=26986'),
minZoom: 6
})
});

map.addControl(new ol.control.ScaleLine({units: 'us'}));
</script>
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: You should try changing all 'EPSG=26986' to 'EPSG:26986'.

Answer (score 1):

Your projection declaration is wrong
Try this:

`proj4.defs("EPSG:26986","+proj=lcc +lat_1=42.68333333333333 +lat_2=41.71666666666667 +lat_0=41 +lon_0=-71.5 +x_0=200000 +y_0=750000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")`

Dont forget to include the pro4js library before declaring your projection definition.